# Jquery AJAX returning error 500 despite the successful execution on server side

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am encountering a problem with codeigniter and JQuery Ajax Post.

My javscript

```
        $('.remove').click(function(){
        var category=event.target.id;
        var id=$('input[name=article_id]').val();
        var p={};
        p['id']=id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/backend.php/blog/removeCategories",
            async:true,
            cache:false,
            data: {id: id, category: category }
            }).done(function(msg){
                jQuery('#category_list').load('/backend.php/blog/refreshCategories/',p,function(str){});
            });
```

My codeigniter's controller

```
 function removeCategories(){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $category_id=$_POST['category'];

        $this->article->removeCategory($category_id,$id);
    }
```

I can't get the ajax function to work because there is always an error 500 received from the server. Although, firebug returns that there is an error loading the resources, the function removeCategories was executed anyways.

Comment: your server side is not doing logging, and while it does something it also dies and has some fatal error. Enable PHP error logging and watch out for fatal errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your error could be in the model.** Use chrome dev toolkit to find out what the returned page content is. `HTTP CODE 500` means server error, typically due to a syntax problem within PHP somewhere.

Also,
In your ajax call you should use `success:` and `error:`. This would allow you to halt execution if the code throws an error.

Why are you calling `backend.php/` Are you not using `index.php` ??

One other way to do this is instead of using `.load()` you can simply pass back the html from the controller and then on `success: function(data){}` append it to the container. This would allow you to monitor whether the ajax call was `error()` or `success()` and act accordingly.

Comment: Hi Mike,

backend.php was a modification I did to CI so as to run two applications in one single CI installation.

Thank you, you just jotted me to find deeper into the codes for syntax errors.

Comment: Hi guys, I have solved the above issue already. Turns out to be a problem in my CI_model. 

I would love to share how I found the problem but I am currently lacked of reputation to post an answer.

But thank you so much people. Kudos =)

Comment: how about you accept one of our answers for pointing you in the right direction? Since it was in the model, i say you give it to me ;)

Comment: I have the same issue and search for solution in google but when I read your answer it enlighten me and check the php side of the code and found out that my query syntax contains ambigous columns... Thanks it really solved my problem...

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your data is being passed properly by making the following changes to the `data` option.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/backend.php/blog/removeCategories",
            async:true,
            cache:false,
            data: {"id": id, "category": category }
            }).done(function(msg){
                jQuery('#category_list').load('/backend.php/blog/refreshCategories/',p,function(str){});
            });
```

The way you have it coded, the key of each key value pair is being set to the variable's value.

Comment: Yes I agree- common misatake in making those classes. Also use fiddler to see what the server says back- It most proboblay says you need to specify ID- If it ran the code anyway.. then you need to trap it because its not supposed to run if its returingon error 500

Comment: It seems to be a legit problem. However the problem persist despite changing my variables as well as your suggested solution.

Comment: Can you post the header info from firebug, so we can see if the data you are passing is being passed properly?

Answer (score 2):

In Codeigniter if you have csrf_protection activated in config it will return Error 500!

To solve this you have to send the csrf value.

**Example:**

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://example.com",
          data: {
                 '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : 
                 '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
                }
       });
```